# How to create a footer with a chapter name and page number?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like a footer that has not only page number, but also the chapter title (heading 1) depending on what chapter the page is in.

How do I add the chapter info to the footer?

Answer (score 48):

The best way to automatically do this is through [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163918%28v=office.10%29.aspx). Assuming the format of your chapters or headings are styles, you need only to add a reference to styles.

In **Word 2010**, while editing the Header & Footer go to *Header & Footer Tools* → *Design* → *Quick Parts* → *Field...*.

In **Word 2013** it's in *Insert* → *Quick Parts → *Field* → *StyleRef* *(thanks to [@techbrunch](https://superuser.com/users/174799/techbrunch))*

[image: Location of Field in the Ribbon UI]

Now in the Field dialog box, choose [`StyleRef`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/field-codes-styleref-field-HP005186193.aspx) from the *Field name* list and your desired heading from the *Style name* list.

[image: Heading name in header]

You can similarly add page numbers by choosing [`Page`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/field-codes-page-field-HP010263655.aspx) in the *Field name* list.

## Additional Notes

Using fields, the data is automatically updated, and you don't need to repeat anything per different pages or sections. In pre-ribbon Word versions (2003 and earlier) simply go to *Insert* → *Field* when editing the header/footer.

Comment: With Word 2013 : Insert > Quick Parts > Field > StyleRef

Comment: What if I my `Heading 1` is a numbered list and I want to display the number with the title as well? This solution displays only the title, not the number.

Comment: I found these instructions incomplete.  Insert > Field, select "StyleRef", and in the field code below it will say "STYLEREF".  Add in quotation marks the name of the style, for example:    STYLEREF "Heading 1".  You can pick these graphically on the Options button, under the "Styles" tab.

Comment: This works even if the document is not divided up into sections (via Insert Break).  Very easy and quick.

Comment: @Vadorequest Insert a second Heading1 StyleRef. Use the first for "Chapter 1" and the second for "Your Chapter Name". You can achieve this by right-clicking the first StyleRef and selecting "Edit Field". Go to field options and check "Insert paragraph # in full context".