# How to show current chapter in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-word-2010, headers

I want to create a header in my Word document. This header should show the current chapter title with its number and text. I already found a [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/319234/microsoft-word-how-to-create-footer-with-chapter-name-and-page-number) for Office 2003, but I am using Word 2010. Could someone help me out?

Comment: should I assume you've already split your document into sections?

Comment: Yes it is already splitted into sections.

Comment: If the document is not split into sections, see http://superuser.com/q/319234/433830 for an extremely quick and easy approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Microsoft Office Support:

### Make the header or footer different in each section or chapter

If your document is divided into sections, you can vary the headers and
footers so that they display different content for each section. For example,
if your document is divided into chapters by using section breaks, the chapter
title can be displayed in the header of each chapter.

** Tip **  If you are unsure whether your document has sections, you can search for them.

[image: Go To Section command]

1. Click **Drafts** on the status bar.
2. On the **Home** tab, in the **Find** group, click **Go To**.
3. Click **Section**.
4. Click **Next** to find section breaks in the document.
5. Draft view makes it easy to see the section breaks in the
   document.

#### Add section breaks to a document

If your document is not divided into sections, you can insert section breaks
where you want the header or footer to vary.

1. Starting at the beginning of the document, place the cursor at the beginning of the page where you want to start varying the header or footer.
2. On the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Breaks**, and then under **Section Breaks**, click **Next Page**.
3. Place the cursor at the beginning of the next page where you want to vary the header or footer, such as the first page of a new chapter.
4. On the **Page Layout** tab, in the **Page Setup** group, click **Breaks**, and then under **Section Breaks**, click **Next Page**.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for every section break that you want in the document.

#### Use a document's section breaks to vary the header or footer

If your document is already divided into sections, you can use the section
breaks to configure headers and footers.

1. Starting at the beginning of the document, click in the first section for which you want to vary the header or footer.
2. On the **Insert** tab, in the **Header & Footer** group, click **Header** or **Footer**.

[image: Word Ribbon Image]

1. Click **Edit Header** or **Edit Footer**.
2. On the **Headers & Footers** tab, in the **Navigation** group, click **Link to Previous** [image: Button image] to break the connection between the header or footer in this section and the previous section.
3. Change the existing header or footer, or create a new header or footer for this section.
4. In the **Navigation** group of the **Design** tab (**Header & Footer** contextual tab), click **Next Section** [image: Button image] to advance the cursor to the header or footer of the next section.
5. On the **Headers & Footers** tab, in the **Navigation** group, click **Link to Previous** [image: Button image] to break the connection between the header or footer in this section and the previous section.
6. Change the existing header or footer, or create a new header or footer for this section.
7. Repeat the previous three steps for all of the sections in the document.

#### Use the same header or footer across section boundaries

In a document where the header or footer varies by section, you can make the
header or footer the same across section boundaries.

1. Double-click the header or footer that you want to preserve across section boundaries.
2. On the **Headers & Footers** tab, in the **Navigation** group, click **Next Section** [image: Button image].
3. Click **Link to Previous** [image: Button image].
4. Office Word 2007 will ask if you want to delete the header and footer and connect to the header and footer in the previous section. Click **Yes**.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very comprehensive article.

Comment: Indeed this is a vary comprehensive article but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Proper answer here, but 8088's answer is useful to formatting this once you're done.

[How to create a footer with a chapter name and page number?](https://superuser.com/questions/319234/how-to-create-a-footer-with-a-chapter-name-and-page-number)

So if you already have your document and you want section-named headers/footers for most stuff but not everything (e.g. not on the title pages etc) then you can

1. Create section-named headers per instruction on link above
2. Create section breaks between bits which should & shouldn't have headers (i.e. you DON'T need to create them between e.g. Chapter 2 & 3, but you DO need to create before chapter 1).
3. Doubleclick on the header to edit it, and delete the header in the pre-Chapter1 section. This should delete all headers there, but not the headers in Chapters 1 & more.